# C How to parse int and char in char array?

Tags: arrays, c, char, compiler-warnings, logical-and

I want to parse `char` and `int` in my `char` array and use them in the code. For example the char array is a3. I am getting a warning: "comparison between pointer and integer."
How can I fix this?

```
bool isValid(char piece[1]){
    if((piece[0] != "a") || (piece[0] != "b") || (piece[0] != "c") || (piece[0] != "d") || (piece[0] != "e") || (piece[0] != "f") || (piece[0] != "g") || (piece[1] <= 0) || (piece[1] > 7))
        return false;
    else
        return true;
```

Comment: Use single quotes so that you have a char and not char* that can be used in comparasions with int so change `bool isValid(char piece[1])` to `bool isValid(char *piece)` then single quotes `piece[0] != 'a'` and so on.

Comment: @Hilal Turfullu What does the function check?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow checks if there is an input out of the board column/row. The board has column 1 to 7 and row a to g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters in expressions like this

```
(piece[0] != "a")
```

the left operand has the type `char` while the right operand has the type `char *` because `"a"` is a string literal. It seems you are going to compare two characters. So instead of string literals use character constants like

```
(piece[0] != 'a')
```

Secondly, the condition in the if statement

```
if((piece[0] != 'a') || (piece[0] != 'b') || and so on...
```

is incorrect. You need to use the logical AND operator instead of the logical OR operator like

```
if((piece[0] != 'a') && (piece[0] != 'b') && and so on...
```

Comment: Use && in if statement differences from situation to situation. && can't give me what i want. But (piece[0] != 'a') solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`char` literals are denoted by single quotes (`'`) not double quotes (`"`), so you should check `piece[0] != 'a'` etc.